# OpenVPN connection failed

Tags: firewall, openvpn, pfsense

suddenly openvpn lost connection to server. The logs are following:

server logs:

Jul 21 00:07:40 openvpn 29858 100.90.2.29:62306 TLS Error: Auth Username/Password was not provided by peer
Jul 21 00:07:40 openvpn 29858 100.90.2.29:62306 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Jul 21 00:07:40 openvpn 29858 100.90.2.29:62306 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting

Jul 21 00:06:17 openvpn 29858 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET6

Jul 21 00:06:17 openvpn 29858 GDG: problem writing to routing socket

Thu Jul 20 23:20:01 2023 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]100.90.2.29:7777 failed: Unknown error
Thu Jul 20 23:20:01 2023 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),connection-failed] received, process restarting

===============================================================================================

client logs:

2023-07-21 09:57:46 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]100.90.2.29:7777
2023-07-21 09:59:48 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]100.90.2.29:7777 failed: Unknown error
2023-07-21 09:59:48 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),connection-failed] received, process restarting
2023-07-21 10:01:56 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]100.90.2.29:7777
2023-07-21 10:01:56 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]100.90.2.29:7777

Any clues as to what is goin on here ? I have rebooted server and also reinstalled everything from scratch but still error showsup